# What are the properties of the differential operator that justify this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I am solving the following differential equation:
$$y'' - y = x^2$$

It is perfectly permissible for me to proceed as follows:

$$D^2y- y = x^2$$

$$y(D^2-1) = x^2$$
$$y = (D^2 - 1)^{-1} \cdot x^2$$
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} D^n\cdot x^2$$
$$y = (-1 - D^2 - D^4...) x^2$$
$$y_p = -x^2 - 2$$

Which specific properties have been used (specifically the second and third step) which justify this?

Similarly, why am I allowed to do this?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$$
$$dy=2xdx$$

In general, which properties hold for the differential operator?

Comment: The first question touches the wide subject of [resolvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism) in functional analysis. The second is separation of variables when solving ODEs. Before the discussion starts again whether $dy/dx$ can be treated as a fraction: Don't care and do it. The solutions you find will always satisfy the ODE which can be checked with utmost rigor afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The operator D does not 'commute' with functions. So one writes
$$ (D^2-1) y = x^2 $$

Multiplication by the pseudo-inverse on both sides from left produces the Neumann geometric series

$$(D^2-1)^{-1} \ (D^2-1) y =- (1-D^2)^{-1} x^2 = - \sum {D^{2n}} x^2 = -(x^2+ 2)$$

The pseudo-inverse of an operator is the inverse on the subspace with the kernel, consisting of all y

$$(D^2-1) y=0$$

is excluded.

So the general solution is that special solution plus any combination of exponentials solving $(D^2-1) y=0.$

The Neumann series representation can be understood, if an eigenbasis of the differential operator is used to expand all functions.

In this basis the differential operator is a diagonal matrix, that can be inverted by taking the inverse diagonal matrix elements on the subspace nonzeero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean by “The operator D does not 'commute' with functions”?

Comment: In general, a linear differential operator acts from the left on functions by the simplified notation  $\frac{[d}{dx}  f(x) =f'(x)$. If functions $f,g$ and differential and integral operators are considered as a non-commutative algebra, a vector space with a bilinear vector product, , the product rule reads $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) g(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) \frac{d}{dx} g(x)$ or $\frac{d}{dx}  f - f \frac{d}{dx} = f'(x)$